# Different results between vectorized code and naive loopy one in Python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

```
logPi=np.random.normal(0,1,3)+10
logB=np.random.normal(0,1,(5,3))+10
logA=np.random.normal(0,1,(3,3))+10
logPi=np.log(logPi/np.sum(logPi))
logA=np.log(logA/np.sum(logA,axis=1,keepdims=1))
logB=np.log(logB/np.sum(logB,axis=1,keepdims=1))
N, M = logB.shape


theta = np.zeros_like(logB)
theta[0] = logPi + logB[0]
for t in range(1,N):
    for i in range(M):
        temp = theta[t-1]+logA.T[i]+logB[t][i]
        theta[t][i]=np.max(temp)
print("loop:\n",theta)


theta = np.zeros_like(logB)
theta[0] = logPi + logB[0]
for t in range(1,N):
    temp = theta[t-1]+logA.T+logB[t]    #theta[t-1]:(3,) logA.T (3,3) logB[t]:(3,)
    theta[t]=np.max(temp,axis=0)
print("vectorized:\n",theta)
```

Above is my toy code. After running, I got the following outputs. The differences are more obvious in the last two rows. Though it's no big deal here, it becomes a problem when N is large. I wonder why there was such a difference between these two codes which look the same. I've looked up some blogs but they are mostly about data dependencies and the order of operations which provided little help. Thx in advance.

```
loop:
[[ -2.13807344  -2.08414176  -2.40187496]
[ -4.18153958  -4.13865644  -4.37805603]
[ -6.16769508  -6.28860493  -6.3818191 ]
[ -8.26547308  -8.33614274  -8.36669173]
[-10.47121378 -10.35391286 -10.38243085]]
vectorized:
[[ -2.13807344  -2.08414176  -2.40187496]
[ -4.23034598  -4.08985004  -4.60149803]
[ -6.25425934  -6.20204067  -6.76141802]
[ -8.22600221  -8.3756136   -8.92005515]
[-10.35594798 -10.46917867 -10.9966534 ]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You vectorization is not the same as you loop code. First for each row of `logA.T` you add add some value of `logB[t]`. So for vectorized form you should add transposed `logB[t]`. Second in loop-code you find the max along the row of `logA.T` so in vectorized form you should use `axis=1`. So for code

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(13)
logPi=np.random.normal(0,1,3)+10
logB=np.random.normal(0,1,(5,3))+10
logA=np.random.normal(0,1,(3,3))+10
logPi=np.log(logPi/np.sum(logPi))
logA=np.log(logA/np.sum(logA,axis=1,keepdims=1))
logB=np.log(logB/np.sum(logB,axis=1,keepdims=1))
N, M = logB.shape


theta = np.zeros_like(logB)
theta[0] = logPi + logB[0]
for t in range(1,N):
    for i in range(M):
        temp = theta[t-1]+logA.T[i]+logB[t][i]
        theta[t][i]=np.max(temp)
print("loop:\n",theta)


theta = np.zeros_like(logB)
theta[0] = logPi + logB[0]
for t in range(1,N):
    temp = theta[t-1]+logA.T+logB[t].reshape(-1, 1)    #theta[t-1]:(3,) logA.T (3,3) logB[t]:(3,)
    theta[t]=np.max(temp,axis=1)
print("vectorized:\n",theta)
```

I get output:

```
loop:
 [[ -2.30160901  -2.07302345  -2.22449041]
 [ -4.18171262  -4.24723468  -4.39804805]
 [ -6.30798908  -6.34130214  -6.49489672]
 [ -8.41830021  -8.5470397   -8.54808458]
 [-10.59480359 -10.67493831 -10.59373409]]
vectorized:
 [[ -2.30160901  -2.07302345  -2.22449041]
 [ -4.18171262  -4.24723468  -4.39804805]
 [ -6.30798908  -6.34130214  -6.49489672]
 [ -8.41830021  -8.5470397   -8.54808458]
 [-10.59480359 -10.67493831 -10.59373409]]
```